# Haskell: Assigning unique char to matrix values if x > 0

Tags: haskell, matrix, increment

So my goal for the program is for it to receive an Int matrix for input, and program converts all numbers > 0 to a unique sequential char, while 0's convert into a '_' (doesn't matter, just any character not in the sequence).

eg.

```
main> matrixGroupings [[0,2,1],[2,2,0],[[0,0,2]]
[["_ab"],["cd_"],["__e"]]
```

The best I've been able to achieve is

```
[["_aa"],["aa_"],["__a"]]
```

using:

```
matrixGroupings xss = map (map (\x -> if x > 0 then 'a' else '_')) xss
```

As far as I can tell, the issue I'm having is getting the program to remember what its last value was, so that when the value check is > 0, it picks the next char in line. I can't for the life of me figure out how to do this though.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is an instance of an ancient art: labelling of various structures with a stream of
labels. It dates back at least to [Chris Okasaki](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/~nr/cs257/archive/chris-okasaki/breadth-first.pdf), and my favourite treatment is by [Jeremy
Gibbons](http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/jeremy.gibbons/publications/uitbaf.pdf).

As you can see from these two examples, there is some variety to the way a structure may be
labelled. But in this present case, I suppose the most straightforward way will do. And in Haskell
it would be really short. Let us dive in.

### The recipe is this:

- Define a polymorphic type for your matrices. It must be such that a matrix of numbers and a
  matrix of characters are both rightful members.
- Provide an instance of `Traversable` class. It may in many cases be derived automagically.
- Pick a monad to your liking. One simple choice is `State`. *(Actually, that is the only choice I
  can think of.)*
- Create an *action* in this monad that takes a number to a character.
- Traverse a matrix with this action.

### Let's cook!

- A type may be as simple as this:

  ```
  newtype Matrix a = Matrix [[a]] deriving Show
  ```

  It is entirely possible that the inner lists will be of unequal length — this type does not
  protect us from making a *"ragged"* matrix. This is poor design. But I am going to skim over
  it for now. Haskell provides an [endless depth](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/dm13dn/how_far_is_haskell_as_used_in_production_from/) for perfection. This type is *good enough* for
  our needs here.

  We can immediately define an example of a matrix:

  ```
  example :: Matrix Int
  example = Matrix [[0,2,1],[2,2,0],[0,0,2]]
  ```
- How hard is it to define a `Traversable`? 0 hard.

  ```
  {-# language DeriveTraversable #-}

  ...

  newtype Matrix a = Matrix [[a]] deriving (Show, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
  ```

  Presto.
- Where do we get labels from? It is a side effect. The function *reaches somewhere*, takes a
  stream of labels, takes the head, and puts the tail back in the extra-dimensional pocket. A
  monad that can do this is `State`.
- It works like this:

  ```
  label :: Int -> State String Char
  label 0 = return '_'
  label x = do
      ls <- get
      case ls of
          [ ] -> error "No more labels!"
          (l: ls') -> do
              put ls'
              return l
  ```

  I hope the code explains itself. When a function *"creates"* a monadic value, we call it
  *"effectful"*, or an *"action"* in a given monad. For instance, `print` is an action that,
  well, prints stuff. Which is an effect. `label` is also an action, though in a different
  monad.  Compare and see for youself.
- Now we are ready to cook a solution:

  ```
  matrixGroupings m = evalState (traverse label m) ['a'..'z']
  ```

### This is it.

```
λ matrixGroupings example
Matrix ["_ab","cd_","__e"]
```

### Bon appetit!

**P.S.**   I took all glory from you, it is unfair. To make things fun again, I challenge you for an exercise: can you define a `Traversable` instance that labels a matrix in another order — by columns first, then rows?

Comment: Thanks so much! Though I wasn't able to use the {-# extension #-} format in my code for some reason, so I had to use :set -XDeriveTraversable.

Comment: @netugi You need to put it before the `module ... where` line.

Comment: Thank you. I just want you to know I did give your exercise a go for a little bit, but I didn't wanna spend too much time on it at the moment since this is for a big university assignment due in a few days. I'll give it another go if I have the free time after that. I do appreciate the challenge, it helped with me understand how the code works better.